# force: inputfield is not working properly for lookup fields inside the aura:iteration

Tags: lightning, lightning-inputfield, forceinputfield

```
    <td valign="top">
          <force:inputField aura:id="lookup"  value="{!v.conitem.CERM__Account__c}"/> <br/>
    </td >
    <td IconName="custom:custom17" valign="top">
        <force:inputField aura:id="lookup"   value="{!v.conitem.CERM__Business_Location__c}"/> <br/> 

    </td>
    <td valign="top">
        <force:inputField aura:id="lookup" value="{!v.conitem.CERM__Commodity__c}"/> <br/> 
    </td> 
    <td valign="top">
        <force:inputField  value="{!v.conitem.CERM__Quantity__c}"/> <br/>
    </td> 
     <td valign="top">
        <force:inputField aura:id="lookup"  value="{!v.conitem.CERM__UoM__c}"/> <br/>
    </td> 
    <td valign="top">
        <force:inputField  value="{!v.conitem.CERM__DeliveryStartDate__c}"/>
    </td>
    <td valign="top">
        <force:inputField  class="slds-input"  value="{!v.conitem.CERM__DeliveryEndDate__c}"/>

    </td>
    <td valign="top">
        <force:inputField  class="slds-input"  value="{!v.conitem.CERM__FuturesMonth__c}"/>
    </td>
    <td >
        <force:inputField value="{!v.conitem.CERM__GoverningGrades__c}"/> <br/>
    </td> 
    <td valign="top">
        <div valign="top">  
            <force:inputField  value="{!v.conitem.CERM__GoverningTerms__c}"/> <br/> 
        </div>
    </td> 
    <td valign="top">
        <div>
            <force:inputField  value="{!v.conitem.CERM__Governing_Weights__c}"/> <br/> 
        </div>
    </td>[![enter image description here][1]][1]
</tr>
```

[image]

Comment: Why don't you use lightning:inputField?

Comment: Yes i used lightning:inputfield it also not rendering the ui in aura iteration.one more thing lightning:iputfield inherits the field label also.here i'm using inside the iteration.so the label is coming every line.

Comment: Can you post your `aura:iteration` code as well?

Answer (score 0):

force:inputField is not rendering fields on UI when being used inside aura:iteration tag or inside nested components in Lightning application.

**Workaround**

> Try using **Lightning:inputField** instead of force:inputField for rendering input
>    fields inside  or inside inner components

Comment: yes, i have tried lightning:inputfield it also not rendering the ui inside the iteration